# UTF-8 encoding and Struts 2.1.7

Tags: java, jquery, json, utf-8, struts2

As per title I've a problem with charset encoding, I see the `?` instead of special character for Polish language.

I will try to explain my issue.

I have a page JSP with this code :

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

I have an Ajax call written in this way:

```
$.ajax({
                url :urlToPrepend + "url/load.action",
                type : "post",
                dataType : "json",
                async:false,
                data : 
                {
                    repeat: 0,
                    changedLayoutName:activeLayoutRS,
                    sapNamesWithConfig:selectedColumnSAPNamesWithConfigRS,
                    columnNamesWithConfig:selectedColumnNamesWithConfigRS,
                    sortBy:sortByWithConfigRS,
                    extractConfig:extractConfigRS,
                    savedParams:savedParams
                },
                success : function(data) 
                {
                     data.columNames
```

`data.columnNames` contains a list from Java `Action` with Polish label. If I put the debug point with Firefox I see at that point that the strings have mark question instead of the correct accent.

In the Java `Action` I tried to put these code lines:

```
response.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
```

I tried also to put in struts.properties the parameter:

```
struts.i18n.encoding=UTF-8
```

I tried to add the `param encoding in the` struts.xml` for the specific action.

Nothing has work, have you some ideas for the solution?

**UPDATE:**

the `columnNames` data is an `ArrayList` :

```
columnNames = new ArrayList<String>();
```

is filled with `getText()` method:

```
columnNames.add(getText(columnData.getValue())))
```

where `columnData.getValue()` is a key for properties file (example : `catalogue=Rodzina produkt\u00f3w`). If I put an expression test in debug I see the label coded as well `Rodzina produktów` but in json response I see this :

```
"columnNames":["","","Pojazd","Rodzina produkt�w"
```

the `ArrayList` is put in `jsonData` with this code:

```
jsonData.put("columnNames", columnNames);
```

**UPDATE 2:**

I discovered that we're using for some action a plugin named GZIP. For this one the result success part in the `struts.xml` file is defined in this way:

```
    <result name="success" type="json">
        <param name="excludeNullProperties">true</param>
        <param name="root">jsonData</param>
        <param name="enableGZIP">true</param>
    </result>
```

Do you know how it works?

**UPDATE 3:**

Removing `enableGZIP` all works as expected, so the only question left is regarding this particular plugin.

Comment: Post the code that produce JSON in your action.

Comment: You haven't mentioned any gzip plugin in your post. How do you use it?

Comment: Try to explicitly add `encoding` parameter to result configuration: `<param name="encoding">UTF-8</param>`.

Comment: Also which version of S2?

Comment: Thanks Aleksandr, I've already tried with encoding parameter, it seems that is ignored. Until I keep the enableGZIP parameter the encoding fails,

Comment: 2.1.7 is very old version and afaik there **isn't** json plugin for that version. Also it seems there was a bug with encoding gzip-ed json in some versions. Solution -> upgrade.

Comment: Ok infact is an existing project, the start date is 2011. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

jQuery has the [`parseJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/) method that you can use to parse JSON

```
var data = $.parseJSON(data);
```

It will decode UTF-8 characters.

<kbd>[Running demo](http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/?id=be72b82dd0bf3c2333564cf12a49cdb6)</kbd>

<kbd>[Running demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/Lmahe3r7/)</kbd>

Comment: The problem is in the step between java and call back of ajax call, because when the data arrives in javascript code the labels are already corrupted.

Comment: If you get data in the format "Rodzina produkt\u00f3w" then you can decode it. Did you send it in this way?